# PHP Compare two nested arrays to get a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to subtract parts of one nested array from another, but I'm having difficulty specifying the parts that I want to subtract as both values are numbers.

My arrays are, for example:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 43 [quantity] => 4 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 43 [quantity] => 2 ) )
```

And after the subtraction I want the Result to be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 43 [quantity] => 2 ) )
```

I'm using the following code to perform the subtraction, but I can't stop it from subtracting the `id` from itself:

```
foreach(array_keys($arrayA) as $id)
{
    foreach(array_keys($arrayA[$id]) as $type)
    {
        $newArray[$id][$type] = $arrayA[$id][$type] - $arrayB[$id][$type];
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Could someone please tell me how I can just effect the `[quantity]` part of the array, without changing the `[id]`?  With the code as it is I get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 0 [quantity] => 2 ) )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ar1 = array(0 => array('id' => 43, 'quantity' => 4));
$ar2 = array(0 => array('id' => 43, 'quantity' => 2));
$new_array = array();

foreach($ar1 as $key => $value)
{
    $new_array[$key] = array('id' => $value['id'], 'quantity' => ($value['quantity'] - $ar2[$key]['quantity']));
}
```

---

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [id] => 43 
            [quantity] => 2 
        ) 
)
```

Comment: Aaagh. Just beat me to it!

Comment: That's basically what I started with, and moved on to the other way of trying it because this way didn't seem to work, but this is working perfectly now so I must have made a mistake with my original.  Thank you! :)